# Installing 32bit Node on Mountain Lion

Tags: node.js, appjs

I'd like to start playing with AppJS as a possible solution for an upcoming project, but I'm new to NodeJS and haven't managed to find a way to install 32bit Node (required by AppJS) on OSX Mountain Lion. Is there a tutorial that I've missed that someone can point me to? I do have nvm installed and I keep seeing indications that it's possible to install a 32 bit version, but I just haven't been able to find out *how*.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After downloading the source you simply need to run:

```
./configure --dest-cpu=ia32
```

You could also download the prebuilt binary or installer from [Node's website](http://nodejs.org/download/).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I already had node installed via homebrew, so I guess I was a little too focused on something in that direction. I'll take a closer look at these options.